# Custom hook for window resize

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm working on creating a custom hook that captures the browser window size to let me know if it's mobile or not.  At the moment, my issue is React telling me it can't retain the variable value of screenSize within the useEffect hook.  How do I get around this?

```
export default function useIsMobile() {
    let screenSize = 0;
    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            screenSize = window.innerWidth;
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {
                screenSize = window.innerWidth;
            })
        }
    }, [screenSize]);
    
    return screenSize <= 768;
}
```

Comment: use the `useRef` hook: `const screenSizeRef = useRef(0);`. Declaring `screenSize` as local variable inside `useIsMobile` hook will reset the variable everytime this hook is called; Using `useRef` hook will persist the value across different renders of your component.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use the `useRef` hook to create a variable on the component level, then use the `.current` property to update it's value.

```
export default function useIsMobile() {
    const screenSize = useRef();

    useEffect(() => {
        window.addEventListener("resize", () => {
            screenSize.current = window.innerWidth;
        });
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", () => {
                screenSize.current = window.innerWidth;
            })
        }
    }, []);
    
    return screenSize.current <= 768;
}
```

Note that I also removed the dependency from the `useEffect` hook because it's not needed. Because it's a ref and not a state, you will use the same variable every time which means that you don't need to re-register the listener.

**UPDATE**

The way useRef work will not trigger a re-render which is why there is a need to use a `useState` hook instead.
This code snippet will cause a re-render every time the mode changes.

```
const getIsMobile = () => window.innerWidth <= 768;

export default function useIsMobile() {
    const [isMobile, setIsMobile] = useState(getIsMobile());

    useEffect(() => {
        const onResize = () => {
            setIsMobile(getIsMobile());
        }

        window.addEventListener("resize", onResize);
    
        return () => {
            window.removeEventListener("resize", onResize);
        }
    }, []);
    
    return isMobile;
}
```

Note that I moved `getIsMobile` outside the component because it doesn't contain any logic related to it and also so it could be called on the default value of the `useState` hook to save a re-render right when the hook first loads.

Comment: The only issue I'm seeing here is, when the screen gets resized, I'm not getting a return value.  I only get the return on initial load of the page.  The return statement never gets hit.

Comment: That's right, in this case, I would use a `useState` hook instead of a `useRef` hook, because you do want to trigger a re-render.
But then, I would only update it when the state change so it won't re-render the whole app every time the width change but only when the mode changes.
I will edit my answer for you :D

Comment: Perfect.  I'm a bit new to the custom hooks portion of React so this was a great knowledge increase.  Thanks!

Comment: No problem! Good luck with that, there is a lot to learn with React.

Comment: It should be `useState(getIsMobile)` not `useState(getIsMobile())`. That will prevent useless calls on every re-render. Not a big deal in this case but it's a good practice in general.